# Troubleshooting parallel code

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos, parallel-processing, profiling

What tools are there for troubleshooting parallel programs?

Say I have a code that performs worse than expected (4 times instead of theoretical 8 times  of serial version executing speed). I suspect the cause is either some locking caused by threads accessing shared variables (say adjacent elements of a shared vector), or locking caused by threads accessing heap (which I suppose is also a shared resource). But I don't know what tools are there available to check what might be the cause of excessive thread sleeps, threads switching, etc. E.g. profiler will tell me what function took how much time, and perhaps that there was a lot of activity related to threads management, but not what the cause and state of threads was (or perhaps I don't know how to use one well).

I'm working in C++ on OS X.

Comment: Nice, but does not help without any code. There are no fortune-tellers here!

Comment: I can post some offending code if more people will say that's really needed, but I am asking about tools available when dealing with a family of problems, not a solution to a specific issue.

Comment: There's a nice parallel profiler for dotnet in VS (shows you which thread is waiting for what), but I don't know of any such tool for other platforms. You can always start by timing each potentially waiting code section such as synchronization primitives. Dump measured wait times to a log. If there's some kind of contention there's a chance you will be able to work out the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following may be of interest

[Vampir](http://www.vampir.eu/features) -- costs money

[DTrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTrace) -- is already installed on your Mac, provides the tools you need, but is far from an out-of-the-box solution

[TAU](http://www.cs.uoregon.edu/Research/tau/news.php)

Those are just the first three tools which spring to mind, I'm sure some more diligent googling will turn up more.

Your final comment *perhaps I don't know how to use one well* is well made, these tools generally require a significant commitment to use them, to understand what they are telling you and to make appropriate and performance-enhancing modifications to your programs.